# how to complete the 3rd step of tensorRT zip installation process?

Tags: nvidia, tensorrt

I can't understand the whole process as it says I have to replace the versions of tensorRT , cuda, cuDNN versions of particular download. What particular download they are talking about?

https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html#installing-zip

Here is the full of 3rd step.Please clarify with explanation:

Unzip the TensorRT-7.x.x.x.Windows10.x86_64.cuda-x.x.cudnnx.x.zip file to the location that you chose. Replace:

```
7.x.x.x with the TensorRT version
cuda-x.x with the CUDA version, and
cudnnx.x with the cuDNN version for your particular download.
```

P.S:New to TensorFlow and tensorRT machine learning .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to actually "replace" anything, but the `x` letters.
You will do that automatically by selecting a version of TensorRT that is suitable for your system.

**Example:**

Before you install TensorRT you have to install a version of CUDA and cuDNN.

For Windows 10, according to [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html#installing-zip), this should be:

> ```
> CUDA 10.2, 11.0 update 1, 11.1 update 1, or 11.2
> cuDNN 8.0.5
> ```

Suppose you did install `CUDA 10.2` and `cuDNN 8.0.5` and want to install `TensorRT 7.2.1.6`. Then, the file you are looking for would be named: `TensorRT-7.2.1.6.Windows10.x86_64.cuda-10.2.cudnn8.0.zip`

This is the file you are supposed to download and extract.